# Square root of a stochastic process

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I need help with the following problem. How can I derive $d\sqrt v$ using Ito's lemma for the following process:

$$d\sqrt v=(\alpha−\beta \sqrt v)dt+\delta dX$$

The parameters $\alpha, \beta, \delta$ are constant. Using Itô's lemma show that

$$dv = (\delta^2 + 2\alpha\sqrt v − 2\beta v)dt + 2\delta \sqrt vdX$$

any ideas?

Comment: Please make it clear that $d$ is constant or a notation for differential ?

Comment: Also see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to write equations.

Comment: thanks for the hint. as i am new to this forum. will try better

Answer (score 2):

It is really easy so I show you the solution, the important thing being to make some progress to try to understand it and to apply it in some other context.

Let's note $Y_t= \sqrt{V}_t$ then $Y^2_t=V_t$ (supposing $V$ is a positive process by the way).

So let's apply Itô's lemma with $f(Y)= Y^2$ we get : 
\begin{align}
dV_t=df(Y_t)&= \frac{1}{2}.\frac{\partial^2 f(Y)}{ \partial Y^2} d⟨Y⟩_t+ \frac{\partial f(Y)}{ \partial Y}dY_t\\
 = d\langle Y\rangle_t+ 2 Y_tdY_t
&= (\delta^2 + 2.Y_t.(\alpha -\beta. Y_t))dt +2\delta.Y_t.dX_t\\
&=(\delta^2 + 2.\alpha .\sqrt{V}_t-2.\beta.V_t).dt +2\delta.\sqrt{V}_t.dX_t
\end{align}

NB: $\frac{1}{2}.\frac{\partial^2 f(Y)}{ \partial Y^2} d⟨Y⟩_t=\frac{1}{2}.2.d⟨Y⟩_t$
As $d⟨Y⟩_t=⟨\delta.dX⟩_t=\delta^2.d⟨X⟩_t=\delta^2.dt$ giving the result.

Thank's for pointing out my mistake and also changed my notation on quadratic variation which was confusing. 
Best regards

Comment: sorry but i think your solution is not exactly right. as the right answer should be "dv = (δ^2 + 2α√v − 2βv)dt + 2δ√vdX. could you also describe how the δ term is generated. thank you for more detail about this

Comment: @ userxxx: edited.